# How can I build Angular2 material theme and deploy in the server?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design

I have downloaded the following theme [Angular2 Material](http://md-angular2.creative-tim.com/#/dashboard) created by Creative Tim. Now I can run my application using the command "`npm start`" as per their **Github** instruction.

I want to build my application then I'll deploy it on my server

Do I need to  write any task for building the application like we have `"ng build --prod --aot"` when we use **angular-cli**

Comment: it looks that the project doesn't use angular cli and doesn't use any webpack or browserify or even gulp, not tasks are declared on npm to build it so I assume you gonna need to do it manually, I'd recommend you to implement webpack

Comment: This template does not even include any angular code. (Despite the word angular in its name). It is only based on twitter-bootstrap.